# Как узнать путь к файлу?

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! У меня есть файлы `xxx.exe` и `yyy.exe`. При запуске файла `xxx.exe` он запускает `yyy.exe`. Но как узнать путь к файлу `yyy.exe` через `xxx.exe`?

Comment: Если вы не знаете, то как же программа узнает то ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все сам нашел.

> Функция: FileSearch(const FileName, DirList: string): string;
>
> Модуль: SysUtils
> Описание: Функция осуществляет поиск файла FileName в каталогах, указанных в параметре DirList. Имя файла должно быть представлено в DOS-формате. Список каталогов DirList представляет собой строку, содержащую наименования каталогов, разделенных точками с запятой (например, `'C:\;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\TEMP'`). Если файл найден, то функция возвращает полный путь к файлу, а иначе возвращается пустая строка.